# Java XStream cannot find class in Maven directory

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am using XStream and when I run my application for a module called Webserver directory: org/westbank/webserver

But if I have it in certain other modules, it parses fine without the error.. I am confused. Even if i make a new module and try it, I get the error, but most of the other modules I have work if I add TestService to it and load it from that path.

My XML:

```
<XML>
 <service class = "org.westbank.webserver.authentication.TestService">
    <name>Test</name>
    <identifier>14</identifier>
    <vital>true</vital>
 </service>
</XML>
```

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "main"
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : org.westbank.webserver.authentication.TestService
class               : org.westbank.configuration.XMLConfiguration
required-type       : org.westbank.configuration.XMLConfiguration
converter-type      :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /XML/service
line number         : 2
version             : 1.4.9
-------------------------------
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException:     org.westbank.webserver.authentication.TestService
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the XStream library you need to add your Maven module as a Dependency from the module you are trying to call the other modules' class from.

IE:

I use Configuration module to call TestService from Webserver module, I need to make sure Configuration module has Webserver module added as a dependency.